# Pushing JSX to array

Tags: reactjs, antd

So I am going through my nested objects recursively, pushing menu items to the menu I created as this code shows:

```
let menu = [];
this.createDropDown(menu, objects)
return(menu);

createDropDown = (menu, objects) => {
if(Object.keys(objects).length === 1){
  menu.push(
  <Menu.Item key={Object.keys(objects)}>{Object.keys(objects)}</Menu.Item>
  );
}else{
  for(var k in objects){
    menu.push(<Menu.Item key = {Object.keys(objects[k])}>{k}</Menu.Item>,
    <SubMenu>{this.createDropDown(menu, objects[k])}</SubMenu>);
  }
}
}
```

The menu I created is returned to the render:

```
render(
     return(
      <Menu onClick={handleClick} style={{ width: 256 }} mode="vertical">
      {this.createMenu()}
      </Menu>
    );
)
```

The UI outputs a huge mess, I tried it with return() directly (without creating a menu and pushing to it, but I can't iterate through all objects as the process terminates with the first "Object.keys(objects).length === 1" encountered), and it displayed the items and the submenus. Any idea why React is doing that?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: The menu is not rendering correctly, the items are stuck on each other, no sub-menus...!

Comment: Is there a way I can modify my function is order to return JSX directly in a right way? Else why is the array of JSX not rendering correctly?

Comment: you're pushing the menu.item and the submenu to the same array. shouldn't they be children of a the menu.item?

Comment: Yes they are children of a MenuItem! So what should I do in this case?